# Scale and draw a polygon from latitude and longitude

Tags: php, math, gis, gd, coordinate-transformation

I have a set of coordinates of some fields that I can easily draw on a map. Here's an example:

```
45.60859921    19.24758575
45.60869489    19.24816738
45.60538637    19.24872261
45.60535008    19.24841258
45.60662288    19.24802522
45.60660895    19.24791747
```

What I would like to do is to create an image representation of that field, using GD, like the image below, just without the background. Input would be size of a square image in pixels and field's coordinates, and code would fit the field polygon in that square with some padding.

These polygons are small, couple of hectares at most, so precise projection is not important. It's the shape in a box that I'm after.

[image]

Comment: Did you try using Imagick DrawPolygon ? See [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.polygon.php) . Please make an attempt and if you still have problems then let us know

Comment: Drawing a polygon with known X and Y coordinates is easy, it's the translation from longitude and latitude to X and Y and scaling that's evading me. Examples that I found usually draw geography objects on an image of a known size and coordinates. This is different. Or I am missing something? Example where you use that method to achieve desired output would be great.

Comment: In my understanding, converting is not too difficult , something like (or similar to)
`X=r⋅cos(lat.) ⋅cos(long.) `
and `Y=r⋅cos(lat.) ⋅sin(long.)`  . Please refer to another stackexchange post [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/10450/conversion-gps-longitude-latitude-to-x-y-of-local-reference-frame) -- please test by yourself which forumula suits you . Again, please make an attempt by yourself first (using whatever approach which you think is correct) and if you still have problem, post your code and telling us what is/are the problems

Comment: I would start by computing min(lat), max(lat), min(lon) and max(lon).

Comment: Thinking outside the box: use something like selenium or playwright or even electron and just have a little webpage with a Leaflet map without a background tileset, and load that page, have its JS draw the geo poly you need, and then screenshoot it? Because you _could_ math this, but you could also just have something else draw it for you and steal its image output =)